# VHDL Error - Washing Machine - unresolved signal is multiply driven

Tags: vhdl, project, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

Currently coding washing machine code shown below for project. I am new to VHDL and need help with an error message.

"Unresolved signal is multiply driven"

```vhdl
library IEEE; --Basic Standard Logic Package
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Washing_Machine is

    port (Clk : in  STD_LOGIC; --Clk    
          Reset : in  STD_LOGIC; --Reset - Makes the Current State reset back to the start e.g. Soak.           
          DoubleWash: in  STD_LOGIC; --Button pressed to change state           
          START_STOP : in STD_LOGIC; -- Start/Stop switch          
          LidSensor: in STD_LOGIC; -- Lidsensor -> Checks if Lid Open or Close          
          LEDs: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); --LEDs shows State
          Segment: out  STD_LOGIC_Vector (6 downto 0)); --7-Segmenet shows State

 end Washing_Machine;

architecture Behavioral of Washing_Machine is

    type state_type is (Soak, Wash, Rinse, Spin, Idle, SecondWash, SecondRinse, Done); --State types defined    
    signal Next_State, Curr_State: State_Type;   
    signal Counter : unsigned(26 downto 0);
   
   -- Time durations    
    constant Soak_Duration : unsigned(26 downto 0) := to_unsigned(100000000, 27); -- 1 Second    
    constant Wash_Duration : unsigned(26 downto 0) := to_unsigned(300000000, 27); -- 3 Seconds    
    constant Rinse_Duration : unsigned(26 downto 0) := to_unsigned(500000000, 27); -- 5 Seconds    
    constant Spin_Duration : unsigned(26 downto 0) := to_unsigned(900000000, 27); -- 9 Seconds

begin

process(Clk, Reset) --The logic for Clk and Reset

    begin
        if Reset = '1' then --If reset is HIGH -> State go backs to Soak -> Start of Sequence        
            Curr_State <= Idle;        
            Counter <= (others => '0');

        elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
        
            if START_STOP = '1' and LidSensor = '0' then            
                Curr_State <= Next_State;                
                Counter <= (others => '0');
            
            elsif LidSensor ='1' then            
                Curr_State <= Idle;

            end if;        
        end if;
    end process; 
    
    process(DoubleWash, Curr_State)
    begin 

        if DoubleWash = '1' then
        
            case Curr_State is 
                when Idle =>                
                    if START_STOP = '1' then
                        Curr_State <= Soak;                        
                        Counter <= (others => '0');                    
                    end if;

                when Soak =>                
                    if Counter < Soak_Duration then                
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;
                
                    else                
                        Next_State <= Wash;                    
                        Counter <= (others => '0');                
                    end if;

                when Wash =>
                
                    if Counter < Wash_Duration then                    
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;
                    
                    else
                        Next_State <= Rinse;                    
                        Counter <= (others => '0');
                    
                    end if;

                when Rinse =>
                
                    if Counter < Rinse_Duration then                    
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;
                    
                    else                                
                        Next_State <= SecondWash;
                    
                    end if;

                when SecondWash =>
                
                    if Counter < Wash_Duration then                    
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;
                    
                    else
                        Next_State <= SecondRinse;                          
                        Counter <= (others => '0');
                    
                    end if;
                
                when SecondRinse =>
                    
                    if Counter < Rinse_Duration then                    
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;
                    
                    else                    
                        Next_State <= Spin;                    
                    end if;
                
                when Spin =>
                
                    if Counter < Spin_Duration then                    
                        Counter <= Counter + 1;     
                    
                    else                    
                        Next_State <= Idle;                        
                        Counter <= (others => '0');
                    
                    end if;

                when others =>
                
                    Curr_State <= Idle;

            end case;    
        end if;  
    end process;

    process(Curr_State, START_STOP) --Logic for Curr_State and START_STOP Button
    begin
    
            case Curr_State is
                when Idle => --Idle
                    if START_STOP = '1' then                    
                        Curr_State <= Soak;                        
                        Counter <= (others => '0');                    
                    end if;
                  
            when Soak=> --Soak
                
                if Counter < Soak_Duration then                
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;
                
                else                
                    Next_State <= Wash;                    
                    Counter <= (others => '0');                
                end if;
            
            when Wash=>
            
                if Counter < Wash_Duration then                
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;
                
                else                
                    Next_State <= Rinse;                
                    Counter <= (others => '0');
                
                end if;
            
            when Rinse =>            
                if Counter < Rinse_Duration then                
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;
                
                else                    
                    Next_State <= Spin;                    
                    Counter <= (others => '0');
                
                end if;
            
            when Spin =>            
                if Counter < Spin_Duration then                
                    Counter <= Counter + 1;     
                
                else                
                    Next_State <= Idle;                    
                    Counter <= (others => '0');
                
                end if;
            
            when others =>            
                Curr_State <= Idle;
            
        end case;
            
    end process;
            

    process(Curr_State) --State shown physically via LEDs 
    begin

        case Curr_State is
            when Soak =>            
                LEDs <= "0001"; -- Binary -> Decimal Number -> LED lights up as 1 -> First LEDs in sequence 
                Segment <= "1001111"; -- Binary -> 7-Segment Display-> 7-Segment lights up as 1 -> First LEDs in sequence 

            when Wash =>            
                LEDs <= "0010"; -- Binary -> Decimal Number -> LED lights up as 2 -> Second LEDs in sequence 
                Segment <= "0010010"; -- Binary -> 7-Segment Display -> 7-Segment lights up as 2 -> Second LEDs in sequence 

            when Rinse =>            
                LEDs <= "0100"; -- Binary -> Decimal Number -> LED lights up as 3 -> Third LEDs in sequence 
                Segment <= "0000110"; -- Binary -> 7-Segment Display -> 7-Segment lights up as 3 -> Third LEDs in sequence 

            when Spin =>            
                LEDs <= "1000"; -- Binary -> Decimal Number -> LED lights up as 4 -> Fourth LEDs in sequence 
                Segment <= "0000110"; -- Binary -> 7-Segment Display-> 7-Segment lights up as 4 -> Fourth LEDs in sequence 

            when others =>            
                LEDs <= "0000"; -- Binary -> Decimal Number -> LED lights up as 0 -> No LEDs in sequence
                Segment <= "0000001"; -- Binary -> 7-Segment Display -> 7-Segment lights up as 0 -> No LEDs in sequence 

        end case;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I want it to be able to function similar to a normal washing machine.

I also would like to add Token Deposit in future.

Comment: You have three multiply driven signals: `curr_state`, `next_state` and counter. This means they are assigned in more than one process. This is like different devices trying to drive the same wire with different values. If it were binary, and they were both driving a '1' and a '0', what resulting value would you expect? The state signals are not resolved because they are a custom type. You need to modify the code so that the state signals are only driven in a single process.

Comment: In addition, you are missing signals from the sensitivity list - `counter` is missing from the list of the state machine process. But counters cannot work in an async (non-clocked) process. Move the counter to the clocked process.

Comment: @Tricky you should post this as answer.

Comment: Tricky's 'answer' isn't demonstrable to future readers who might be lead astray trying to demonstrate the problem and solution. The design needs changes to simulate much less be implemented. Adding counter to the sensitivity list would infer a relaxation oscillator., the +1 provides for at least one bit of inversion to what should be a register, and is a combinatorial assignment providing feed back. Comments seek clarification, suggest corrections, and provide additional information. The OP can implement suggestions and perhaps answer, possibly without value to future readers without a [mcve].